# Google Maps Circle object custom css

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API v3 `Circle` object to draw circles on the map.
I want to customize the css of that circle, by adding some css animations.

I know that I can use a custom overlays, but I like the Circle class because I can easy set a radius and the circle scales automatically.

I just want to edit some css properties of the circle, but looking at the docs there is nothing.

How can i do that?

This is the Circle code that i use currently:

```
var latLng = {
   lat: 0,
   lng: 0
};      
var radius = 200; //200 meters
var fillColor = "#40ad00";
var strokeColor = "#40ad00";

var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
   center: latLng,
   radius: radius,
   strokeColor: strokeColor,
   strokeOpacity: 0.25,
   strokeWeight: 1,
   fillColor: fillColor,
   fillOpacity: 0.1,
   map: map
});
```

What i want to do is to have this animated circle on the map.

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}

div.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: spin 5s infinite cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.80, 0.135, 1);
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
      opacity:0;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
      border-color: #FFFFFF;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #FFFFFF;
      }
    15% {
      opacity:1;
      }
    70% {
      opacity:1;
      border-color: #d100ff;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 1px #d100ff;
      }
    100% {
      opacity:0;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 1px #FFFFFF;
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: provide your code with the circles.

Comment: I don't think you have options past their basic stroke, fill, opacity, etc unfortunately. But you might be able to make a polygon, and change the points on it, depending on what kind of animation you need. But this would be done w/ js, not css.

Comment: I'm using css3 animations, not js.
As i said, i can create an OverlayView with my custom html/css, but the problem is that i don't know how to mimic the Circle object.. eg: size it by meters like the radius property..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it is not possible to customize the style of the `Circle` object of the Google Maps API.

The solution is to create a custom `OverlayView` that mimic the `Circle` object.
The key is to let the `Circle` API calculate the bounds, and apply the bounds to the custom `OverlayView`.

Here is the complete code.
The custom style is applied with the `circle` class.

```
CustomCircle = function(center, radius, map) {
  //Calculate the bounds with the Circle API
  this.bounds_ = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: center,
    radius: radius
  }).getBounds();
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
};
CustomCircle.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CustomCircle.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  var circle = document.createElement('div');
  circle.className = 'circle'; //class with custom styling
  circle.style.width = '100%';
  circle.style.height = '100%';
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(circle);

  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
CustomCircle.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
CustomCircle.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
```